# User level bounce buffer for fs io ? Why write file buffer address space should be aligned?

Tags: linux, io, filesystems, posix, memory-alignment

I saw a piece of code doing disk io like this :

```
static bool is_aligned(unsigned char *buffer) {
  return ( ((unsigned long)buffer) & (DISK_PAGE_SIZE -1)) == 0;
}


void do_write_IO(int fd, unsignced char *buffer, unsigned long buffer_bytes) {
  ...

  if (is_aligned(buffer)) {
    write_to_file(fd, buffer, io_size);
  } else {
    // bounce buffer is an aligned memory space.
    // if buffer not aligned, copy to an aligned address
    // and do fs write. WHY ?
    // What are the benefits ? 
    memcpy(bounce_buffer, buffer, io_size);
    write_to_file(fd, bounce_buffer, io_size);
  }

  ...
}

// Just call posix write, write output to fd, with bytes_to_write size.
static void write_to_file(int fd, 
          unsigned char *output,
          unsigned long bytes_to_write) 
{
  __sync_fetch_and_add(&stat_bytes_written, bytes_to_write);
  while(bytes_to_write) {
    unsigned long bytes_written = write(fd, output, bytes_to_write);
    if(bytes_written == -1UL) {
      if(errno != EAGAIN) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << 
          "Stream writeout unsuccessful:" << strerror(errno);
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
    else {
      output += bytes_written;
      bytes_to_write -= bytes_written;
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed that it write to file with a buffer that address space aligned. 
So, Is there any benefit that writing to a file with an aligned buffer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume "working properly" is a benefit.  For that to happen, you need to satisfy the preconditions of each function you call.

`write_to_file` requires an aligned buffer if `write` does, and that is device-dependent.  Probably your `fd` is opened with `O_DIRECT`.  The `open` man page says:

> The `O_DIRECT` flag may impose alignment restrictions on the length and address of user-space buffers and the file offset of I/Os.

and

> Under Linux 2.4, transfer sizes, and the alignment of the user buffer and the file offset must all be multiples of the logical block size of the file system. Under Linux 2.6, alignment to 512-byte boundaries suffices.

If you don't respect this precondition, the `write` man page documents an error:

> **`EINVAL`**
>       `fd` is attached to an object which is unsuitable for writing; or the file was opened with the `O_DIRECT` flag, and either the address specified in `buf`, the value specified in `count`, or the current file offset is not suitably aligned.

Comment: YES! And exactly, fd is opened with O_DIRECT. Thank you very much !